# Ruby on Rails Syntax Confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am starting to learn Rails and I am confused as heck.

```
<%= form_for :story, url:'create' do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :title %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>

<% end %>
```

So, the way I understand is that form_for is a method which takes a model. I pass in the :story. Even if I replace the :story with :post it will work as expected.

The url is set as url: instead of :url (Why colon after works and colon before does not)

The following does not work:

```
<%= form_for @story, {url => "create"} do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the `initialize` method of the [ActionView::FormHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)

`:story` is a [symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Symbol.html). In ruby, symbols which are essentially constants are expressed with a colon before the string.

which creates

```
<form action="/story" method="post">
```

`url: 'create'` is a ruby [hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html) which uses symbols as keys and can be written as

```
{url: create} or { :url => "create"}
```

Comment: Are you sure about {url => "create"} because it does not work. See the updated question.

Comment: Essentially I was trying to explain difference between symbol and hash, regarding your question on colon. Since Ruby 1.9 rails supports new hash format which also has symbols.

Comment: should be { :url => "create" }

Comment: @josh yes was a typo, fixed it. Hope it helps OP.